# How to get rid of black spot from the view

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency

With the alpha texture. Applied on the mesh. From the top view its look good with the transparent zig zag edge. When i view to side view. I can see black spots. How to get rid of those black spots. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmUE8.jpg

Comment: I think you should use your texture as a displacement, not as alpha to mask out parts of your mesh. Did you explore that possibility ?

Comment: @Gorgious can you make little more clear & file is attached